# how to add notification in the Stackbuidler without caching the data?

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create notifications but for this purpose i am saving the data every time in an array like

```
            String []events = new String[100];
            events[number]  = msg.getText().toString();
```

and later On I am adding it like

```
             for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

                inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
            }
```

instead i want to show the notifications without caching the data like above.